# Передача параметра в метод с помощью кнопки

Tags: php, html

имеется класс с методами [отсюда](https://github.com/rorystandley/MySQL-CRUD-PHP-OOP/blob/master/class/mysql_crud.php):

```
    class Database
{
    public function select($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null){}    
    public function insert($table,$params=array()){}
    public function delete($table,$where = null){}
    public function update($table,$params=array(),$where){}
}
```

Как реализовать вызов этих методов с параметрами, вводимыми пользователем на странице(при помощи текстбоксов и кнопок)?

Comment: Делаете нужную форму и отправляете её на нужный скрипт для обработки, либо как вариант аяксом, если не нужна перезагрузка страница. А в чем собственно возникли трудности?

Comment: В полном непонимании сути работы кнопок и текстбоксов в HTML.

Comment: Я делал кнопки которые направляли на 4 разные страницы и каждая страница вызывала свой метод. Потому тоже интересно как правильно.

Comment: Как вариант создаёте 4 формы. При нажатии на кнопку, отправляется данная форма на нужный скрипт, где соответственно происходит нужная нам обработка. 
По поводу непонимания, почитайте про формы и их отправку, ничего сложного нет совсем. 
Примерная форма для select:

`<form method="post" action="myScript.php">
Параметр 1<input type="text" name="join">
Параметр 2<input type="text" name="where">
<input type="submit">
</form>`

При нажатии на кнопку отправить данная форма передаётся для обработки в скрипт, указанный нами в action.

Comment: Далее из $_POST выдираем нужные нам переменные и обрабатываем как нам нужно. При необходимости передаём это через аякс.

Comment: То есть у вас будет для каждого параметра свой инпут. А там, где мы должны передавать массив параметров, как вариант, можно использовать `<textarea></textarea>` где переменные перечисляются через запятую.

Comment: @DaVASrK ТЕПЕРЬ ТЫ ОБЯЗАН НАПИСАТЬ ПОЛНЫЙ КОД, итить капс, автору - прочитайте основы, Котеров PHP, а уж потом пытайтесь что-то делать.